# How to print out step by step process in MergeSort

Tags: java

I'm having trouble printing out a MergeSort.  I need help printing out each step by step process as it's sorting an ArrayList.

The following example is from a InsertionSort, as I had it print at every single time it swapped two elements in the ArrayList:

11 79 60 45 START

11 79 60 45

11 60 79 45

11 45 60 79 FINISH

Is there anyway to do this for MergeSort while showing the entire array from start to finish (like above?)

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Merge 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Merge run = new Merge();
        run.test();
    }

    public void test ( )
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            numbers.add(new Integer(1 + (int)(Math.random() * 100)));
        }
        printArray(numbers);
        mergeSort(numbers);
        printArray(numbers);
    }

    public void printArray (ArrayList<Integer> array)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-5d",array.get(i).intValue());
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }

    public void mergeSort (ArrayList<Integer> array) 
    {   
        int length = array.size();
        if (length < 2)
        {
            return;  // the array is already sorted in this case
        }
        // divide
        ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        int i = 0;

        while (i < length/2)
        {
            array1.add(array.remove(0)); // move the first n/2 elements to array1
            i++;
        }
        while (!array.isEmpty())
        {
            array2.add(array.remove(0)); // move the rest to array2
        }

        mergeSort(array1);
        mergeSort(array2);
        merge(array1,array2,array); 
    }

    public void merge (ArrayList<Integer> array1, ArrayList<Integer> array2, ArrayList<Integer> array)
    {   
        while (!array1.isEmpty() && !array2.isEmpty())
        {
            if ((array1.get(0).compareTo(array2.get(0)) <= 0))
            {
                array.add(array1.remove(0));
            }
            else
            {
                array.add(array2.remove(0));
            }
        }
        while(!array1.isEmpty()) // move the remaining elements of array1
        {
            array.add(array1.remove(0));
        }
        while(!array2.isEmpty()) // move the remaining elements of array2
        {
            array.add(array2.remove(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you have so far, and we can help to expand from there.

Comment: Prefix each line of your code with 4 spaces to get it to show up correctly in your post.

Comment: What does "keeps denying me to post the code" mean? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; got it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you passed some offset to `mergeSort`, you may be able to print the sub-array indented over to where it would be in the full array as you make swaps, but since you are only passing portions of the array down, you won't be able to show the full array in this manner.  However, there is a faster way that would allow you to.

Instead of making new arrays and passing them down, pass the array and 2 indices, the begin and end point.  So you say `mergeSort(array, 0, n)` for the first, then `mergeSort(array, 0, n/2)` and `mergeSort(array, n/2, n)` for the recursive calls.  You do your splitting and merging only within those bounds.  Then as you merge, you can print out the whole merged array.  This would show the step at each merge.  At the bottom level, it would show the 1-1 swap (if it occurs).  That's the only "step-by-step" you could see in a merge sort.

Answer (score 1):

With out seeing your code it's hard to know exactly but I grabbed a Mergesort Implementation from here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html.
I've updated it to print out like you want.

```
public class Mergesort 
{
    private int[] numbers;
    private int[] helper;

    private int number;

    public void sort(int[] values) 
    {
        this.numbers = values;
        number = values.length;
        this.helper = new int[number];

        System.out.println("START");

        mergesort(0, number - 1);

        System.out.println("END");
    }

    private void mergesort(int low, int high) 
    {
        // Check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high) 
        {
            // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            // Sort the left side of the array
            mergesort(low, middle);
            // Sort the right side of the array
            mergesort(middle + 1, high);
            // Combine them both
            merge(low, middle, high);
        }
    }

    private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) 
    {

        // Copy both parts into the helper array
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) 
        {
            helper[i] = numbers[i];
        }

        int i = low;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = low;

        // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
        // to the original array
        while (i <= middle && j <= high) 
        {
            if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) 
            {
                numbers[k] = helper[i];
                i++;
            } 
            else 
            {
                numbers[k] = helper[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
        while (i <= middle) 
        {
            numbers[k] = helper[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }

    }

    private void printArray()
    {
        for(int x : numbers)
            System.out.print(x + " ");

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to print to the console you can build the output to a String of the output and return it when you're all done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little Merge sort algorithm program. I copied the algorithm from 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort. You can just run it as a JUnittest or run the main method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

/**
 * Simple MergeSortTest
 */

public class MergeSortTest extends TestCase {


private static int FIRST_ENTRY = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MergeSortTest mergesorttest = new MergeSortTest();
    Integer [] unsortedInt = {1,38, 27, 110, 9, 82, 10, 100, 299, 13};
    List<Integer> unsorted = Arrays.asList(unsortedInt);
    List<Integer> sorted = mergesorttest.mergeSort(unsorted);
    System.out.println(sorted.toString());
}

public void testMergeSort() {
    Integer [] unsortedInt = {1,38, 27, 110, 9, 82, 10, 100, 299, 13};
    List<Integer> unsorted = Arrays.asList(unsortedInt);
    List<Integer> sorted = mergeSort(unsorted);
    assertEquals("[1, 9, 10, 13, 27, 38, 82, 100, 110, 299]", sorted.toString());
}

private List<Integer> mergeSort(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> result;
    List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
    int middle;
    int counter;
    if (list.size() <= 1) {
        return list;
    }
    middle = list.size() / 2;

    for (counter = 0; counter < middle; counter++)  {
        left.add(list.get(counter));
    }

    for (counter = middle; counter < list.size(); counter++)  {
        right.add(list.get(counter));
    }   

    left = mergeSort(left);
    right = mergeSort(right);
    result = merge(left, right);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}

private List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (!left.isEmpty() || !right.isEmpty()) {
        if (!left.isEmpty() && !right.isEmpty()) {
            if (left.get(FIRST_ENTRY) <= right.get(FIRST_ENTRY)) {
                handle(left, result);
            } else {
                handle(right, result);
            }
        } else if (!left.isEmpty()) {
            handle(left, result);
        } else if (!right.isEmpty()) {
            handle(right, result);
        }
    }
    return result;  
}

private void handle(List<Integer> list, List<Integer> result) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(list.get(FIRST_ENTRY));
        list.remove(FIRST_ENTRY);
    }
}
```

}