# Printing the entire process of mergeSort

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, mergesort

I have a spec which requires me to create a GUI with a text field and three buttons. The text field will take 5 numbers and store them as array, and depending on which button you click, they will be sorted through either bubbleSort, mergeSort, or quickSort, displaying every step taken.

Example for what my bubbleSort output will be to show what I mean:

5 3 2 6 2 (Start)

3 5 2 6 2

[snip]

2 2 3 5 6

2 2 3 5 6 (End)

Before I make the GUI, which should be simple enough (the purpose of the spec is to teach sorting, not GUI mechanics), I figured it would be a good idea to make a separate class for each of these and test them in their own mains to make sure I understand the logic. bubbleSort was simple enough, and I seem to be making progress on quickSort, but I can't manage to get mergeSort to work how I want it to.

I've tried quite a few things, including making an external counter that forces the next line to start when 5 terms have been printed, all to no avail. The only other resource I've been able to find on the subject is here: [How to print out step by step process in MergeSort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406294/how-to-print-out-step-by-step-process-in-mergesort), but I'm having trouble grasping how I should apply the accepted answer, which seems like it could make sense.

My current code is as follows, with my faulty prints commented out. The sort logic itself seems to work fine however.

```
public class MergeSort {

public static void mergeSort(int[] list) {
    if (list.length > 1) {
        int[] firstHalf = new int[list.length / 2];
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length / 2);
        mergeSort(firstHalf);
        int secondHalfLength = list.length - list.length / 2;
        int[] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
        System.arraycopy(list, list.length / 2, secondHalf, 0,
                secondHalfLength);
        mergeSort(secondHalf);
        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
        // for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        // System.out.print(list[j] + " ");
        // counter++;
        // if (counter == size) {
        // System.out.println();
        // counter = 0;
        // }
        // }
        // System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] list1, int[] list2, int[] temp) {
    int current1 = 0;
    int current2 = 0;
    int current3 = 0;

    while (current1 < list1.length && current2 < list2.length) {
        if (list1[current1] < list2[current2]) {
            temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
//              for (int j = 0; j < current3; j++) {
//                  System.out.print(temp[j] + " ");
//              }
//              for (int j = 0; j < current1; j++) {
//                  System.out.print(list1[j] + " ");
//              }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }
    }

    while (current1 < list1.length) {
        temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
    }

    while (current2 < list2.length) {
        temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] list = { 5, 3, 2, 6, 2 };
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(list[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    mergeSort(list);
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(list[j] + " ");
    }
}
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] list) {
    if (list != null && list.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("mergeSort - ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

        int[] firstHalf = new int[list.length / 2];
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length / 2);
        System.out.println("The first half (before) - ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstHalf));
        mergeSort(firstHalf);
        System.out.println("The first half (after) - ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstHalf));

        int secondHalfLength = list.length - list.length / 2;
        int[] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
        System.arraycopy(list, list.length / 2, secondHalf, 0,
                secondHalfLength);

        System.out.println("The second half (before) - ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf));
        mergeSort(secondHalf);
        System.out.println("The second half (after) - ");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf));

        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
        System.out.println("After - ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick reply. I went ahead and cloned my work, and then replaced my mergeSort method with what you provided. I had managed to get something similar to this output before, but I can certainly say this seems easier to follow as far as my understanding the logic goes than what I had done before, so that's helpful in itself. I'll probably need to tweak the before and afters though, because there's quite a few duplicates.

Additionally, I was hoping to have it in a format like this:
53262 -> 35262 (maybe this one should be skipped?) -> 35226 -> etc. Is that possible?

Comment: I was just showing you where to print (it's around your recursion, and arraycopy method). You might also want to print in your merge. It's up to you, you asked for the entire process to be printed. That means down to 1 element lists, and then merging back to your sorted array.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried printing in both the mergeSort and merge methods, at varying places. The biggest issue I'm running into is combining the smaller lists (1, 2, 3 elements) into a list including the otherwise unaffected five numbers to express the step taking place, giving my output a uniform appearance. But with the nature of how the elements are broken down in mergeSort, I'm starting to question how feasible such a format might actually be. Either that, or there's something I'm simply not thinking of/understanding.

Comment: Yep, I've seen that example - that's more or less what I want to show up, so when the elements check whether there should be a swap (turn red), any swaps would update, with the unaffected black cells showing up around it. 65318724 -> 56318724 -> 56138724, etc. I apologize if your answers have been hinting at how to do it in that specific manner - if so, I'm either not following, or not seeing how to apply it properly.